# Firebase RealtimeDatabase connection with second database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtimedatabase for my IOs App. I doing it with swift.

Now I want to connect to the Second Database. Can you guys tell me how to connect?
I only have access to the main Database.

[**secound database Database**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzEXx.png)

Answer (score 0):

See the Firebase documentation on [connecting to multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects), which shows this for iOS:

```
// Configure with manual options. Note that projectID and apiKey, though not
// required by the initializer, are mandatory.
let secondaryOptions = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "1:27992087142:ios:2a4732a34787067a",
                                       gcmSenderID: "27992087142")
secondaryOptions.apiKey = "AIzaSyBicqfAZPvMgC7NZkjayUEsrepxuXzZDsk"
secondaryOptions.projectID = "projectid-12345"

// The other options are not mandatory, but may be required
// for specific Firebase products.
secondaryOptions.bundleID = "com.google.firebase.devrel.FiroptionConfiguration"
secondaryOptions.trackingID = "UA-12345678-1"
secondaryOptions.clientID = "27992087142-ola6qe637ulk8780vl8mo5vogegkm23n.apps.googleusercontent.com"
secondaryOptions.databaseURL = "https://myproject.firebaseio.com"
secondaryOptions.storageBucket = "myproject.appspot.com"
secondaryOptions.androidClientID = "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com"
secondaryOptions.deepLinkURLScheme = "myapp://"
secondaryOptions.storageBucket = "projectid-12345.appspot.com"
secondaryOptions.appGroupID = nil
```

But please read the entire page, as there are a few more steps, depending on your exact requirements.